# Non-Copyable STL Allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, allocator

I want to create a non-copyable allocator (in C++14) which just allocates a fixed memory block a `std::vector` can use. I want to prevent the allocator (and therefore also the vector) from being copyable to prevent the user from accidentally allocating memory. The allocator is only intended to be used with a `std::vector` or maybe `std::string`.

So my allocator has a copy constructor like this:

```
static_allocator(const static_allocator<T>&) = delete;
```

When calling:

```
std::vector<int, static_allocator<int>> vvv(static_allocator<int>(3));
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Vector_impl::_Vector_impl(const _Tp_alloc_type&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = static_allocator<int>; std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type = static_allocator<int>]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:128:20:   required from ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Vector_base(const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = static_allocator<int>; std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = static_allocator<int>]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:265:18:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = static_allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = static_allocator<int>]’
```

The error comes seems to come from the fact that in `stl_vector.h:265` there is no constructor for rvalue allocators defined:

```
/**
*  @brief  Creates a %vector with no elements.
*  @param  __a  An allocator object.
*/
explicit
vector(const allocator_type& __a) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
: _Base(__a) { }
```

While the code deeper actually supports rvalue allocators but those are not called because the rvalue is taken by reference by the constructor mentioned above.

Is this a missing feature in C++14 or am I missing some option? It is also strange that the allocator is copied when constructing the vector for no obvious reasons.

Full code example can be found here: https://onlinegdb.com/ByqXwQ4k4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  From [[container.requirements.general]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements.general#8)

> [...] **All other constructors for these container types take a `const allocator_­type&` argument**. [ Note: If an invocation of a constructor uses the default value of an optional allocator argument, then the allocator type must support value-initialization. — end note ] **A copy of this allocator** is used for any memory allocation and element construction performed, by these constructors and by all member functions, during the lifetime of each container object or until the allocator is replaced.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So you cannot pass a move only allocator to any of the container constructors that take an allocator.

Comment: You're an allocator

Comment: @SombreroChicken Hun?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [requirements for an `Allocator` type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) your allocator type needs to satisfy [`CopyConstructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible) which means that you can't delete your copy con:

> ```
> A a1(a)
> A a1 = a
> ```
>
> Copy-constructs `a1` such that `a1 == a`. Does not throw exceptions.
>   (Note: every `Allocator` also satisfies [`CopyConstructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible))

Answer (score 1):

You said: *I want [...] to prevent the user from accidentally allocating memory.*

But the solution you propose *I want to prevent the allocator (and therefore also the vector) from being copyable* as said in other answers is not feasable. As it is written your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Others have answer to your *attempt solution*. So I will focus on the problem only. Because it is possible to write a standard compliant allocator that full-fill your need: *to prevent the user from accidentally allocating memory.*

There are many alternative implementation that may suit your need. But I don't know precisely what you are looking for so I propose bellow an example that can be adapted, following the requirements in [allocator.requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements):

```
const size_t buffer_size = 4096;
unsigned char buffer[buffer_size];
void* _sbuffer = buffer; //or atomic



template<class T>
class allocator{
   void* buffer = exchange(_sbuffer,nullptr);//could be done atomically
   bool allocatable=buffer?true:false;

   public:

   using value_type = T;

   T* allocate(size_t n){
      if (n>buffer_size || !allocatable) throw std::bad_alloc{};
      allocatable=false;
      return static_cast<T*>(buffer);
      }
   void deallocate(T*,size_t){
      if (buffer) allocatable=true;
      }
   //Here the intersting part:
   allocator select_on_container_copy_construction(){
      return allocator{};
      }

   allocator() =default;

   //this copy constructor is only used internaly
   //but will not be used to propagate the allocator
   //from one container object to an other 
   //(see select_on_container_copy_construction)
   allocator(const allocator& other) =default;

   allocator(allocator&& other)
     :buffer{exchange(other.buffer,nullptr)}
     ,allocatable{exchange(other.allocatable,false)}
     {}
   allocator& operator=(const allocator&) =delete;
   allocator& operator=(allocator&& other){
      buffer=exchange(other.buffer,nullptr);
      allocatable=exchange(other.allocatable,false);
      return *this;
      }

   using propagate_on_container_copy_assignment = false_type;
   using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = true_type;
   using propagate_on_container_swap = true_type;


   //any allocator can deallocate memory provided by an other
   static constexpr bool is_always_equal = true;

   friend bool operator==(const allocator&,const allocator&){
       return true;
       }

   friend bool operator!=(const allocator&,const allocator&){
       return false;
       }
   };
```

Demonstration on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2370022dfaceebc4)

It is fragile because if the allocator is constructed outside the container, then copy constructed and these copies later used to initialize containers... You can go to implementation defined behavior, for example, for libstdc++, you could declare the dangerous constructor private:

```
template<class T>
struct allocator{
   /*...*/
   friend std::_Vector_base<T,allocator>;
   friend std::allocator_traits<allocator>;
   private:
   allocator() =default;
   allocator(const allocator& other) =default;
   public:/*...*/
   };
```